# Class relationship in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My project(Django Rest Framework) is blog app where logged in users can Post some texts and any logged in users can add comment to Posts.

What are the changed I need to make in the Post and Comment class to establish the logic ?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings


class User(AbstractUser):
       #User model

class Post(models.Model):
    postdata = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a ForeignKey pointing to your Post model in the Comments model:

```
post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
```

As a good practice, keep using settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of User directly